# ios - how do I detect if and which item was tapped in a list of items in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

I have a list of text items which populate a list.  The code for it looks like this:

```
// CREATING EACH CELL IN THE LIST
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"business";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    }



    cell.textLabel.text = [cellTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    // CLOSE THE SPINNER
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    // return the cell for the table view
    return cell;
}




-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.itemList.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize = [[cellTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 30;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    

}
```

What I want to do is to give the person a choice to edit each item. One way it makes sense to do that is by making it a 2-column list and on the right side column to make a character like ">" so they can tap it and it will give them an option to edit the item.

How can that be done in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Well...when a row is tapped didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called, so just do what you need to let the user edit that row in there? Look into edit mode for tableview. Or do you want a custom editing view (like another screen for editing)

Comment: @yuf I was thinking to give them an option like "Are you sure you want to edit this section?" and if they say yes, I would take them to  a screen for that.  Is that clunky-ish ux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture a row click:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Use indexPath.row to find your selection
    ...
}
```

If you watch to capture a click on just a button, or similar:

```
[self.buttono addTarget:self action:@selector(doAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you wish to use the `accessoryType`, you would place this code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Pick an indicator to suit your need/look
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Then you action something on the click like so

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Perform action for this click on row indexPath.row
}
```

If you `indexPath.row` isn't enough to differentiate between your clicks (I can't see why it wouldn't be!) then you can always use `setTag` on your disclosure button.

Comment: how difficult would it be to change what I have into a 2-column design where the right side column click would be the only place where that tap would get sensed?

Comment: Also, what info about the row can be extracted? Like its order number? Or some unique_id which I can possibly attach?

Comment: If you don't want to capture presses on the entire row, don't use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. I'll update my answer regarding your second question.

Answer (score 1):

```
  [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

also

```
  [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]; //if you have a sender
```